# my c program freezes after asking for user input. Please help. I've tried everything

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char firstname[40];
    char lastname[40];
    printf("what's your name? \n");
    scanf(" %s %s ", firstname, lastname);
    printf("hello there %s %s \n", firstname, lastname);
    return 0;
}
```

the program freezes after scanning firstname and lastname

Comment: looks fine for me https://godbolt.org/z/T3ejbx

Answer (score 2):

The trailing space in your format string is consuming any whitespace after you enter the first and last names, which includes newlines.  This means you would need to enter some non-whitespace after the first and last name before `scanf` returns.

Get rid of the spaces on either end of the format string.

```
scanf("%s %s", firstname, lastname);
```

Comment: woah.. I always though of trailing whitespace as harmless.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Nothing's harmless when `scanf()` gets involved.  I have no idea why that gets taught so much.  No one uses it in real life - at least not for long.

Comment: The middle space is not needed in the format string either.  The first and middle spaces are harmless; the trailing space is diabolical.